# Proper way to reassign pointers in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, pointers

EDIT: I know in this case, if it were an actual class i would be better off not putting the string on the heap. However, this is just a sample code to make sure i understand the theory. The actual code is going to be a red black tree, with all the nodes stored on the heap.

I want to make sure i have these basic ideas correct before moving on (I am coming from a Java/Python background). I have been searching the net, but haven't found a concrete answer to this question yet.

When you reassign a pointer to a new object, do you have to call delete on the old object first to avoid a memory leak? My intuition is telling me yes, but i want a concrete answer before moving on.

For example, let say you had a class that stored a pointer to a string

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::string *str;

public:
MyClass (const std::string &_str)
{
    str=new std::string(_str);
}

void ChangeString(const std::string &_str)
{
    // I am wondering if this is correct?
    delete str;
    str = new std::string(_str)

    /*
     * or could you simply do it like:
     * str = _str;
     */ 
}
....
```

In the ChangeString method, which would be correct?

I think i am getting hung up on if you dont use the new keyword for the second way, it will still compile and run like you expected. Does this just overwrite the data that this pointer points to? Or does it do something else?

Any advice would be greatly appricated :D

Comment: It is most likely that you shouldn't be allocating a string with `new` in the first place. Do you have any specific reason for that?

Comment: A more natural thing to do here, would still be: `*str = _str;` (no need to throw away one string and create another if you just want to assign the contents)

Comment: That is pretty much what my question centers about. If i did it that way, would i have i get a memory leak? From the comments bellow, it sounds like i would.

Comment: If you want  ared-black tree, what's wrong with std::map?

Comment: @neil, the entire purpose of the red black tree is just to get me intruduced to the language/syntax/etc. Every time i pick up a new language, I start by building a red black tree to make sure i understand the basics (it is pretty much my "hello world")

Comment: @user272689: Naturally you *won't* get a memory leak with `*str = _str;` (because `std::string` itself doesn't leak). Note that this is working with existing objects, not *addresses*. - @Neil: Any C++ programmer should be capable of managing memory manually and implementing a RAII class with builtin language constructs, so there's nothing wrong doing these things as an exercise.

Comment: @UncleBens Thank you, that is exactly what i was looking for (wasn't sure if it would override the object the pointer pointed to, or create a new one somewhere resulting in a memory leak).

It is now my understanding that '*pObject = DifferentObject' will just overwrite the old object that pObject points to, and will not result in a memory leak.

Thanks

Comment: @user: It's not accurate to say that `*pObject = DifferentObject` will overwrite the old object. It calls the assignment operator of pObject which will probably copy the relavent information from DifferentObject.  (In the case of std::string, yes, pObject will end up containing the same characters as DifferentObject did.)

Comment: @kyeana: Simply being able to hack together a red-black tree which compiles and *seems* to work doesn't really teach you anything useful about C++. In C++, satisfying the compiler is the least of your problems. Writing a red-black tree as a learning exercise is a fine idea, but to actually *learn* something from it, you'll have to make sure that it's 1) correct, and 2) reasonably idiomatic C++. The former is hard to verify on your own, and the second is impossible. What are you going to do to ensure you *learn* something from this exercise?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you must deallocate the old instance and create another one, you should first make sure that creating the new object succeeds:

```
void reset(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string* tmp = new std::string(str);
    delete m_str;
    m_str = tmp;
}
```

If you call delete first, and then creating a new one throws an exception, then the class instance will be left with a dangling pointer. E.g, your destructor might end up attempting to delete the pointer again (undefined behavior).

You could also avoid that by setting the pointer to NULL in-between, but the above way is still better: if resetting fails, the object will keep its original value.

---

As to the question in the code comment.

```
*str = _str;
```

This would be the correct thing to do. It is normal string assignment.

```
str = &_str;
```

This would be assigning pointers and completely wrong. You would leak the string instance previously pointed to by `str`. Even worse, it is quite likely that the string passed to the function isn't allocated with `new` in the first place (you shouldn't be mixing pointers to dynamically allocated and automatic objects). Furthermore, you might be storing the address of a string object whose lifetime ends with the function call (if the const reference is bound to a temporary).

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think you need to store  a pointer to  a string in your class? Pointers to C++ collections such as string are actually very rarely necessary. Your class should almost certainly look like:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::string str;

public:
MyClass (const std::string & astr) : str( astr )
{
}

void ChangeString(const std::string & astr)
{
    str = astr;
}
....
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pinpointing here, but

```
str = _str;
```

would not compile (you're trying to assign _str, which is the value of a string passed by reference, to str, which is the address of a string). If you wanted to do that, you would write :

```
str = &_str;
```

(and you would have to change either _str or str so that the constnest matches).

But then, as your intuition told you, you would have leaked the memory of whatever string object was already pointed to by str.

As pointed earlier, when you add a variable to a class in C++, you must think of whether the variable is owned by the object, or by something else.

If it is owned by the object, than you're probably better off with storing it as a value, and copying stuff around (but then you need to make sure that copies don't happen in your back).

It is is not owned, then you can store it as a pointer, and you don't necessarily need to copy things all the time.

Other people will explain this better than me, because *I* am not really confortable with it. 
What I end up doing a lot is writing code like this :

```
class Foo {

private :
   Bar & dep_bar_;
   Baz & dep_baz_;

   Bing * p_bing_;

public:
   Foo(Bar & dep_bar, Baz & dep_baz) : dep_bar_(dep_bar), dep_baz_(dep_baz) {
       p_bing = new Bing(...);
   }

   ~Foo() {
     delete p_bing;
   }
```

That is, if an object depends on something in the 'Java' / 'Ioc' sense (the objects exists elsewhere, you're not creating it, and you only wants to call method on it), I would store the dependency as a reference, using dep_xxxx.

If I create the object, I would use a pointer, with a p_ prefix.

This is just to make the code more "immediate". Not sure it helps.

Just my 2c.

Good luck with the memory mgt, you're right that it *is* the tricky part comming from Java ; don't write code until you're confortable, or you're going to spend hours chasing segaults.

Hoping this helps !

Comment: Memory management is centered around the idea of whose responsibility is it to allocate/deallocate a given piece of memory. In Java/C#, deallocation is managed by scope & language semantics. In C/C++, you handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule in C++ is that for every object created with "new" there must be a "delete".  Making sure that always happens in the hard part ;)   Modern C++ programmers avoid creating memory on the heap (i.e. with "new") like the plague and use stack objects instead.  Really consider whether you need to be using "new" in your code.   It's rarely needed.

If you're coming from a background with garbage collected languages and find yourself really needing to use heap memory, I suggest using the boost shared pointers.   You use them like this:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
...
boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> myPointer = boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass());
```

myPointer has pretty much the same language semantics as a regular pointer, but shared_ptr uses reference counting to determine when delete the object it's referencing.  It's basically do it yourself garbage collection.  The docs are here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

Comment: Modern C++ programmers create everything with new - but use reference counting to avoid writing delete.  Most C++ programmers work on systems where you need a little bit more memory than a stack (Unless you have a system with a 4gb stack!)

Comment: @josh - correct me if i am wrong, but there are many times when you would need to use the heap (in this case for the red black tree). If we tried to make a large tree entirely on the stack, wouldn't we just stack overflow? Or perhaps you mean we could create the red black tree object on the stack (the end user), and all of the nodes could still be placed on the heap (without the end user have to worry about it)?

Comment: Just remember that reference counting by itself can't detect cycles, it isn't as foolproof as garbage collection.  Not an issue if you're pointing to a standard type, but if you're pointing to custom objects you need to be more careful and understand how to use weak_ptr as well.

Comment: @Martin "Modern C++ programmers create everything with new" - say what??? Or perhaps I'm just an ancient C++ programmer.

Comment: Ya, I figured "Modern" might rub some people the wrong way.  But I stand by it. I've been programming in c++ off and on in three (almost four!) decades now and you can predict the age of c++ code by looking how often "new" and "delete" are used.

Comment: @Neil, partly frustration at a framework I'm using - they went for reference counting in a big way! It's necessary because of the amount of data it throws around but it's a pain not having dtors - the worst of c++ and Java!

Comment: @Josh Three decades is impressive - TC++PL didn't come out until 1985, as did the first external release of C++. The language itself dates back to 1983. So I would say you are a liar and  a troll.

Comment: @tloach:  To be Mr. Picky for a moment, reference counting is a form of garbage collection.  It's simpler to implement but less effective than forms like mark-and-sweep.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just write a class for you.

```
class A
{
     Foo * foo;   // private by default
 public:
     A(Foo * foo_): foo(foo_) {}
     A(): foo(0) {}   // in case you need a no-arguments ("default") constructor
     A(const A &a):foo(new Foo(a.foo)) {}   // this is tricky; explanation below
     A& operator=(const &A a) { foo = new Foo(a.foo); return *this; }
     void setFoo(Foo * foo_) { delete foo; foo = foo_; }
     ~A() { delete foo; }
}
```

For classes that hold resources like this, the copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor are all necessary.  The tricky part of the copy constructor and assignment operator is that you need to delete each `Foo` precisely once.  If the copy constructor initializer had said `:foo(a.foo)`, then that particular `Foo` would be deleted once when the object being initialized was destroyed and once when the object being initialized from (`a`) was destroyed.

The class, the way I've written it, needs to be documented as taking ownership of the `Foo` pointer it's being passed, because `Foo * f = new Foo(); A a(f); delete f;` will also cause double deletion.

Another way to do that would be to use Boost's smart pointers (which were the core of the next standard's smart pointers) and have `boost::shared_ptr<Foo> foo;` instead of `Foo * f;` in the class definition.  In that case, the copy constructor should be `A(const A &a):foo(a.foo) {}`, since the smart pointer will take care of deleting the `Foo` when all the copies of the shared pointer pointing at it are destroyed.  (There's problems you can get into here, too, particularly if you mix `shared_ptr<>`s with any other form of pointer, but if you stick to `shared_ptr<>` throughout you should be OK.)

Note:  I'm writing this without running it through a compiler.  I'm aiming for accuracy and good style (such as the use of initializers in constructors).  If somebody finds a problem, please comment.

Comment: @Roger:  My thanks.  I changed that so that that which assigned to `foo` was `Foo *`.

Answer (score 0):

Three comments:

You need a destructor as well.

```
~MyClass() 
{
    delete str;
}
```

---

You really don't need to use heap allocated memory in this case. You could do the following:

```
class MyClass {
    private: 
        std::string str;

    public:
        MyClass (const std::string &_str) {
            str= _str;
        }

        void ChangeString(const std::string &_str) {
            str = _str;
};
```

---

You can't do the commented out version. That would be a memory leak. Java takes care of that because it has garbage collection. C++ does not have that feature.

Comment: I have a destructor in the actual class im using. This was just supposed to be a sample code to demonstrate my question. Thanks though.

Comment: Yea, i know i dont need to use heap in this case, but i want to understand how this works because there will be times when i need to use the heap (i am going to be making a red black tree, but i wanted to make sure i understand the basic ideas before moving on)

Comment: Gotcha. Wasn't sure where you were coming from.

Comment: Does the third comment help? or should I elaborate?

Comment: Also, there are smart pointers which take care of a lot of memory management for you.  It's important to understand the underlying behavior, but boost::scoped_ptr and boost::shared_ptr are quite useful for production code.

Comment: Your first point is true, but the OP also needs a copy constructor and assignment operator.  Any class that manages resources (e.g., an object allocated on the free store) _must_ have those two user-declared functions and a destructor.

Comment: Yes, thats what im looking for. Just to make sure i understand this, the proper way would be to always call delete first, then use the the new keyword again. Thanks :)

Comment: @user272680:  Also, pay attention to James McNellis' comment.  I don't know whether you realize that you need a copy constructor and assignment operator but left them out of the sample code, or if you didn't know they're necessary, but you seem to be uncertain on the concept.

Comment: @David, yes i do. Like I said, this is just a sample code to show the theory of my question, this isn't anything im actually writting.

Comment: @user272689:  Good, but you seem a little shaky on the pointer use, so I think it best we be explicit, just in case you missed something else.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @David: Not at all. I just started learning this last night so i will gladly take all the advice i can get :)

Answer (score 0):

> When you reassign a pointer to a new object, do you have to call delete on the old object first to avoid a memory leak? My intuition is telling me yes, but i want a concrete answer before moving on.

Yes.  If it's a raw pointer, you must delete the old object first.

There are smart pointer classes that will do this for you when you assign a new value.